# A Bernoulli Trial of Two Poisson Processes: Expected Time Until First Bulb Failure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Beginning at time t=0 we begin using bulbs, one at a time, to illuminate a room. Bulbs are replaced immediately upon failure. Each new bulb is selected independently by an equally likely choice between a Type-A bulb and a Type-B bulb.

The lifetime, X, of any particular bulb of a particular type is an independent random variable with the following PDF:

[image: see image]

Why is the variance and expected value of the time before the first bulb failure equal to 2/3? Any idea of how to get this value? I got this and the answer from https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/fa07/disc/week6hints.pdf .

Comment: You need to provide an indication that you have made some effort to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out what the resulting distribution should be. At first glance, it could seem like a merged Poisson process but I know it's not since the arrival bulbs A and bulbs B are not independent but each has 50% chance of selection upon failure. Any idea of how to get the distribution of the first bulb failure? I need to master the process of deriving distributions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(X)&=\mathsf{E}(X|A)\Pr(A)+\mathsf{E}(X|B)\Pr(B)\\
&=(1)(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{2})\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(X^2)&=\mathsf{E}(X^2|A)\Pr(A)+\mathsf{E}(X^2|B)\Pr(B)\\
&=2(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{2})\\
&=\frac{10}{9}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(X)&=\mathsf{E}(X^2)-\mathsf{E}^2(X)\\
&=\frac{10}{9}-(\frac{2}{3})^2\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is this your downvote?

Comment: How did you know that $E[X^2|A]=2$ and $E[X^2|B]=\frac{2}{9}$? I did not do any downvote. :)

Comment: Warm thanks to the anonymous downvoter! Just calculate the expectation of $x^2$ with the given two pdf.

Comment: Lol, haha that was easy. Thanks. I'll give you an upvote to neutralize the downvote. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are derivations:

$$E[X^{2}|A]=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-x}dx$$
$$=e^{-x}(\frac{x^{2}}{-1}-\frac{2x}{(-1)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-1)^{3}})|\begin{matrix}
\infty\\ 
0
\end{matrix}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}[e^{-x}(\frac{x^{2}}{-1}-\frac{2x}{(-1)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-1)^{3}})]-e^{0}(\frac{0^{2}}{-1}-\frac{0}{(-1)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-1)^{3}})$$
$$=-(-2)$$
$$=2$$

$$E[X^{2}|B]=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}3e^{-3x}dx$$
$$=3e^{-x}(\frac{x^{2}}{-3}-\frac{2x}{(-3)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-3)^{3}})|\begin{matrix}
\infty\\ 
0
\end{matrix}$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}3e^{-x}(\frac{x^{2}}{-3}-\frac{2x}{(-3)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-3)^{3}})-3e^{0}(\frac{0^{2}}{-3}-\frac{0}{(-3)^{2}}+\frac{2}{(-3)^{3}})$$
$$=-3(\frac{2}{-27})$$
$$=\frac{2}{9}$$